# Shadcn Accordion Open/close by default in mobile/desktop

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, radix-ui, shadcnui

I want my accordion to be open by default in desktop
but in mobile devices it should be initially closed.
how can i implement that?

```
<Accordion type="single" collapsible>
  <AccordionItem value="item-1">
    <AccordionTrigger>Is it accessible?</AccordionTrigger>
    <AccordionContent>
      Yes. It adheres to the WAI-ARIA design pattern.
    </AccordionContent>
  </AccordionItem>
</Accordion>
```

im using tailwind in my next.js app soo ifthis can be done by tailwind that would be superb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<Accordion type="single" collapsible defaultValue={window.screen.width >= 768 ? "item" : ""}>
  <AccordionItem value="item" >
    <AccordionTrigger>Is it accessible?</AccordionTrigger>
    <AccordionContent>
      Yes. It adheres to the WAI-ARIA design pattern.
    </AccordionContent>
  </AccordionItem>
</Accordion>
```

Comment: I just updated the answer, please try that